# Qt 5 - у переведённого приложения поменялась высота полосы меню

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Есть приложение на Qt 5. У приложения есть главное меню(сверху) с пунктами File и Edit. Приложение переведено с английского языка на русский через Linguist. Перевод загружен и используется, меню отображается как Файл и Правка. Уже в Linguist полоса меню была огромной, в приложении осталась такой же. Параметры полосы меню в форме по умолчанию. Что случилось, где нужно подкрутить?

[the menu error](![a busy cat http://www.pixic.ru/i/d0r1Z1m225Z9c8F9.png](http://www.pixic.ru/i/d0r1Z1m225Z9c8F9.png)

Comment: Хоть скриншоты покажите.

Comment: В полосе меню снизу и сверху появились отступы, которых быть не должно. Размер самой полосы скачет в зависимости от размера шрифта. Если установить размер принудительно, как раньше, текст пропадает - не влезает. Появляется сбоку в виде стрелочки.

Comment: Сами пункты меню нормальные.

Comment: @ИльяИванов , этот стиль виджетов у Вас системный, раз говорите, что и в Лингвисте такая же проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, скажите подробнее, что имелось в виду. Я поставил кастомную тему, основанную на Fusion. Поменял цвета оформления. Ещё недавно поменял тему Windows на официальную с сайта Microsoft...

Comment: Тему Windows вернул, но без результата.

Comment: @ИльяИванов , да, я спрашивал как раз об этом, устанавливали ли Вы стиль для всей системы или этот стиль, который виден на скриншоте, установлен в приложение индивидуально.

Comment: `qApp->setStyle(
          QStyleFactory::create("fusion"));

       QPalette MyPalette = QGuiApplication::palette();
     int WindowColorLuminosity = 100;

 MyPalette.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(WindowColorLuminosity, WindowColorLuminosity, WindowColorLuminosity));`

Comment: @ИльяИванов , тогда уберите вообще все стили, и тот, что ставили для виндовса, и тот, что ставили для приложения. Всё должно вернуться к исходной точке. Затем добавляйте `fusion` и если отступы в меню снова будут большими, тогда будет ясно, кто виновник.

Comment: Вернулось. Поставил тему Windows Aero(по умолчанию), стиль Fusion убрал. Приложение стало светлым, отступы остались.

Comment: @ИльяИванов , значит остались какие-то хвосты после игры со стилями, иное объяснение найти, вероятно, трудно. Попробуйте запустить что-нибудь из примеров с меню, поставляемых вместе с Qt. Просто чистый проект, который ранее не собирался и не запускался. Если отступы останутся, то будет ясно, что `fusion` отношения к этому не имеет, а системный стиль до конца не зачистился.

Comment: Обалдеть... Кажется, нашёл ошибку. Один лишний перенос строки в названии пункта меню - и целый день отладки. Стили тут не при чём. Пошёл проверять ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал опечатку при наборе имени пункта меню File в Лингвисте. Добавил перенос строки, из-за этого вместо одной строки в названии появились две. Вторая была пустой, её было сложно заметить. Поэтому ошибка в первый раз появилась в Лингвисте, вместе с переводом пришла в приложение, а в Дизайнере её не было. Со стилями это не связано, сейчас все работает, как нужно.